# What do you mean by 240Y / 131 V network specification?

Tags: voltage, ratings, siemens

I was referring an industrial control panel guide for North American market for the network specifications. The specification mentioned a voltage rating 240Y/131V. I am curious, how would one get a phase voltage of 131V for 240V line to line, since for the star network the formuala is: `Eline=√3×Ephase` and it should be `√3×131=226V (which is far away from 240)`. Am I using the wrong concept ? However, for other Y networks shown, the `Eline=√3×Ephase` formula works -
`277×√3=479.778(480V approx.)` and `√3×347=601.021(600V approx.)`
[image]

Answer (score 0):

> *The specification mentioned a voltage rating 240Y/131V. I am curious,
> how would one get a phase voltage of 131V for 240V line to line*

It's likely a typo or a miscalculation. You just can't trust everything you read. It's not a million miles off so no big deal because most equipment designs should easily work without fault (or glitch) with a 5% or 10% variation. 230 x 1.05 = 241.5 volts hence, it really shouldn't be a problem.

In EE design engineering, it's always best to double check what you can (just as you have done in your question - good work).